# R: assigning unique id to a dataframe, based on an incrementing column

Tags: r

My motive is to split this data-frame, such that each split starts with "begin" and ends with "end".

```
Input Format :
> df
   sampleData proc_id
1       begin       0
2         mid       0
3         mid       0
4         mid       0
5         mid       0
6         end       0
7       begin       0
8         mid       0
9         mid       0
10        mid       0
11        mid       0
12        mid       0
13        mid       0
14        end       0
15      begin       0
16        mid       0
17        mid       0
18        mid       0
19        mid       0
20        end       0

> df$proc_id[1:6]<-1
> df$proc_id[7:14]<-2
> df$proc_id[15:20]<-3

Output Format:
> df
   sampleData proc_id
1       begin       1
2         mid       1
3         mid       1
4         mid       1
5         mid       1
6         end       1
7       begin       2
8         mid       2
9         mid       2
10        mid       2
11        mid       2
12        mid       2
13        mid       2
14        end       2
15      begin       3
16        mid       3
17        mid       3
18        mid       3
19        mid       3
20        end       3
```

I have been considering, writing a for loop, and assign a process_id (begin, mid , end being its stages) to each row of the data-frame. Then a split on this process_id would separate each process into a separate data-frame.

Another approach I can up is, to get index of all "begin" items. Then pass it, as extra argument to the function used in apply() call.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach, as I am a newbie in R.
In case there is a package to achieve it, please enlighten me on that as well.

Thanks

Comment: What do you show to us? The column names of the data.frame, the real content? If so, it is a vector, not a data.frame. Please clarify your example.

Comment: updated problem description. Hope is is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks asmohamed, for the solution. 
But i had to tweak your solution, to obtain the desired output. Here is the final solution:

```
> df$proc_id<-0
> begins <- which(df$sampleData=="begin")
> ends <- which(df$sampleData=="end") +1
> inter <- intersect(begins, ends)
> inter<-c(1,inter,length(df$sampleData)+1)
> df$proc_id <- do.call(function(x)rep(x-1, inter[x]-inter[x-1]), list(2:length(inter) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for all "begin" that have "end" before it using this code.

```
begins <- which(df$sampleData=="begin")
ends <- which(df$sampleData=="end") +1 # add one to end indexes to see if they contain a "begin"

#find the intersection
inter <- intersect(begins, ends)

proc_id <- do.call(function(x)rep(x, inter[x]), list( seq_along(inter) ))
```